Measure theory. Prove a set is Borel with measure zero.
Let $\alpha_k > 0$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \alpha_k < \infty$ and $A$ the set of $x \in [0,1]$ such that for an infinite number of natural numbers $q$ exists an integer $p=p(q)$ such that
$$ \bigg |x- \frac{p}{q} \bigg | < \frac{\alpha_q}{q}.$$
$1.$ Prove the set $A$ is Borel.
$2.$ Prove its measure is zero.
My attempt
First, to see $A$ is a Borel set, I tried to express it as unions or intersections of open sets of the interval $[0,1]$ (relative topology). I came to the conclusion that
$$  A = [0,1]  \cap \bigg ( \cap_{n=1}^{\infty}  \cup_{q=n}^{\infty} \bigg(\frac{-\alpha_q + p}{q}, \frac{\alpha_q + p}{q} \bigg ) \bigg).$$
The interval $ \bigg(\frac{-\alpha_q + p}{q}, \frac{\alpha_q + p}{q}\bigg )$ is a Borel set as well as $[0,1]$ and therefore $A$.
Now, using the monotonicity of the measure, we have
$$m(A) \leq m \bigg (\cap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \bigg ) $$
where $$\{A_n\}_n :=\{  \cup_{q=n}^{\infty} \bigg(\frac{-\alpha_q + p}{q}, \frac{\alpha_q + p}{q}  \bigg )   \}_n$$
is a decreasing sequence. Because of subadditivity, we obtain
$$ m(A_n) = m \bigg ( \cup_{q=n}^{\infty} \bigg(\frac{-\alpha_q + p}{q}, \frac{\alpha_q + p}{q}  \bigg )  \bigg) \leq 
\sum_{q=n}^{\infty}  m \bigg ( \frac{-\alpha_q + p}{q}, \frac{\alpha_q + p}{q}  \bigg) = 
\sum_{q=n}^{\infty} \frac{2 \alpha_q}{q} $$
which is a convergent series by the comparison test with $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \alpha_k$, so for some $n$ it is true that $m (A_n) < \infty.$
As a result, we have
$$ m( \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n) = \lim_{n} m(A_n) \leq \lim_{n} \sum_{q=n}^{\infty} \frac{2 \alpha_q}{q} = 0, $$
where we use that the series is convergent.
In conclusion:
$$m(A) \leq m( \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n) \leq 0.$$
I would like to have as little help as possible. Any small hint or correction is welcome. Thank you.

What exactly do you mean by "infinite q natural"? My best interpretation would be "for an infinite number of natural numbers q, there exists an integer p,..." Also you forgot to quantify over p in your expression for A. The rest of your proof looks valid though.

I meant "for an infinite number of natural numbers q". With reference to your second comment, p is fixed every time, can you expand on that?

If p is fixed then the first equality A=... in your proof would yield that A depends on p, which is not the case. You should probably take the union over all possible choices of p.

The proof can be made shorter By using Borel Cantelli lemma instead of proving it in this particular case.

As pointed out in comments, you should be taking a union over $p$, and $p$ is dependent on $q$ so the union on $p$ should be innermost. We get that $A$ is Borel using the following corrected representation.
$$A = [0,1]\cap \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{q=n}^\infty \bigcup_{p=-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac{-\alpha_q+p}{q}, \frac{\alpha_q+p}{q}\right)$$
The rest of your argument is roughly correct, but you'll now have to do extra work to handle $p$ when proving $m(A)=0$. To do this, notice that for any fixed $q$, having $p\leq -\alpha_q$ or $p\geq 2\alpha_q+q$ will put the relevant interval entirely outside of $[0,1]$, so you can restrict $-\alpha_q < p < 2\alpha_q+q$. We can still say $A = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ like you had, but now $A_n$ is defined as follows.
$$\begin{align}
A_n &:= \bigcup_{q=n}^\infty \bigcup_{p=\lceil-\alpha_q\rceil}^{\lfloor 2\alpha_q+q\rfloor} \left(\frac{-\alpha_q+p}{q}, \frac{\alpha_q+p}{q}\right) \\
m(A_n) &\leq \sum_{q=n}^\infty \sum_{p=\lceil-\alpha_q\rceil}^{\lfloor 2\alpha_q+q\rfloor} \frac{2\alpha_q}{q} \\
&\leq \sum_{q=n}^\infty \lceil q+3\alpha_q\rceil\frac{2\alpha_q}{q}
\end{align}$$
Since $\alpha_q\to 0$, we can find $M=\sup\{\alpha_q : q\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and bound $q\leq \lceil q+3\alpha_q\rceil \leq q+3M+1$. This implies $1\leq \frac{\lceil q+3\alpha_q\rceil}{q} \leq 1+\frac{3M+1}{q}$ and thus $\lim_{q\to\infty} \frac{\lceil q+3\alpha_q\rceil}{q} = 1$. We can therefore find $C = \sup\left\{\frac{\lceil q+3\alpha_q\rceil}{q} : q\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$, leading to the following conclusion.
$$m(A_n) \leq 2C\sum_{q=n}^\infty \alpha_q$$
We still get $m(A_n)\to 0$ like you had in your original argument, which leads to $m(A)=0$ the same way.
